# How to do elastic scroll on android browsers with css

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, mobile-browser

I wanna on scroll-end see a "overscroll". it's known as elastic scroll, and it's the normal behaviour in apple devices.

Normally all the question gravitate about disable this behaviour in safari, but I want the oposite.

So is there any way to do elastic scrol with css for android browsers (chromium like and firefox)? or at least with a minimium js?

I already did try scroll-snap variations without any luck

```html
<body>
  <div id="app"><p>A very long lorem ipsum</p></div>
  <div id="scrollOffset"></div>
</body>
```

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
}
#app {
  background-color: aqua;
  scroll-snap-align: start end;
  scroll-snap-stop: always; /*< Do nothing and is disabled in FFx*/
}
#scrollOffset{
  max-height: 25vh;
  height: 25vh;
}
```

Extra notes: did you know firefoxOS had a unique elastic scroll, it was gelatinous, really unique, but market only ask for apple like behaviour T.T